# What is this doing? Listing variables without declaring them?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my code:

```
--this section creates/replaces the C_PND Procedure 
--and passes 2variables
    create or replace PROCEDURE    C_PND
   (
    p_whse in varchar2,
    p_RC OUT INT
   )
--No clue what we're doing here as there is no DECLARE
as
 cv SYS_REFCURSOR;  -- cursor variable
 v_pull_zone locn_hdr.pull_zone%TYPE;
 v_active varchar2(1);
 v_low_wm number(3);
 v_high_wm number(3);
 v_lock_code resv_locn_hdr.locn_putaway_lock%TYPE;

--initializes this variable
BEGIN
p_RC := 0;
--setting values of the the CV
OPEN cv FOR
select code_id,
     nvl(trim(substr(sc.misc_flags,1,1)),'N') v_active,
     nvl(trim(substr(sc.misc_flags,2,3)),'100') high_wm,
     nvl(trim(substr(sc.misc_flags,5,3)),'0') low_wm,
     trim(substr(sc.misc_flags,8,2)) lock_code
from sys_code sc
where sc.rec_type = 'C'
and sc.code_type = 'PND';
--inputting the CV into these variables
LOOP
  FETCH cv INTO v_pull_zone, v_active, v_high_wm, v_low_wm, v_lock_code;

  EXIT WHEN cv%NOTFOUND;
  ............
  ............
  ............
```

I think I understand most of it but my problem comes in with the five lines after the as (lines 6-11 of code snippet).  I'm under the impression that anytime you use variables in PL SQL you have to DECLARE them.  Even if you are using cursor variables.

Am I simply wrong about that? Or is there no need to DECLARE variables in use with CVs?  I also included some comments (prefaced by --) that show what I think what the SQL is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sort of right. You have to declare variables using DECLARE in an anonymous block as in:

```
DECLARE
...
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Your code is a procedure and the DECLARE is implicit after the

```
CREATE OR REPLACE xxx as
(implicit DECLARE)

BEGIN

...

END;
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the clear and concise answer!!

Comment: Hi whenever someone gives you the right/possible answer to your question. Please make sure to show your thanks by accepting their answers. Just some advice. Cheers =)

Comment: @fletch367 By the answer you found the most useful, on the left hand side is a grey checkmark.  Click on it to accept the answer to your question.